# Why is 'zesty' not listed in releases?

Tags: apt

My `apt` has become broken recently for a 17.04 install.

`E: The repository 'http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.`

I didn't change anything and also tried re-making `/etc/apt/sources.list` standard Ubuntu repos and got the same error.

`E: The repository 'http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.`

Shouldn't zesty be listed here? 
http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

What should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 reached end of life at 2018-01-13.  See [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) for how to upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 has reached end of life.  Upgrade to 17.10, or use a long term support release like 16.04. See https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life  for the support life of releases.

Comment: The question is actually "How do I do that?"

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` will work @JhourladEstrella